# 301 redirect router for Django project

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a website building tool created in Django and I'd like to add easy user defined 301 redirects to it.

Webflow has a very easy to understand tool for 301 redirects. You add a path (not just a slug) and then define where that path should lead the user.

[image]

I'd like to do the same for the Django project I'm working on. I currently allow users to set a slug that redirects `/<slug:redirect_slug>/` and they can set to go to any URL. But I'd like them to be able to add, for example, the path for an old blog post `'/2018/04/12/my-favorite-thing/'`

What's the best URL conf to use in Django to safely accept any path the user wants?

Comment: I've posted an answer, did it help? If not can you tell what is missing? I'd be glad to help ;D

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, I'm glad that it helped! Don't forget to award the bounty, so it doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Path Converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) that convert the path parameters into appropriate types, which also includes a converter for urls.

An example would be like the following:

```
path('api/<path:encoded_url>/', YourView.as_view()),
```

As per the docs:

> Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than just a segment of a URL path as with str.

In your view, you can get your URL like this:

```
encoded_url = self.kwargs.get('encoded_url')
```

Comment: You might want to replace that link with this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

Comment: @SMoenig Updated the link, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `RerouteMiddleware` which first checks if the request can be served by the existing URLs from the `urls.py`. If it cannot be served, check if the requested path is from the **old -> new** URLs mapping, if a match found redirect it to the new URL.

Sample piece of code to try it out.

```
    try:
        resolve(request.path_info)
    except Resolver404:
        # Check if the URL exists in your database/constants 
        # where you might have stored the old -> new URL mapping.
        if request.path is valid:
            new_url = # Retrieve the new URL
            return redirect(new_url)

    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```